# Functions handling save as and save buttons are not working

Tags: python, file, tkinter, file-handling

I am trying to build a notepad but I am having problem with my save and saveas buttons as the contents in the TextField don't save, the text document is always returning empty, here is my code:

```
def saveFile():
    global infile
    global in_path
    global txt
    try:
        if in_path == '':
    #save as new file
            in_path = asksaveasfile(initialfile='Untitled.txt', defaultextension='txt',filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*txt")])
            if in_path == "":
                in_path = None
            else:
                #try to save file
                with open(in_path, "w") as infile:
                   data = (txt.get(1.0, END))
                   infile.write(data)

                    #change the window title
                root.title(os.path.basename(in_path))
        else:
            #try to save file
            with open(in_path, "w") as infile:
                infile.write(txt.get(1.0, END))
                #change the window title
                root.title(os.path.basename(in_path))
    except:
        pass        
def saveAs():
    global infile
    global in_path
    global txt
    try:
    #save as new file
        in_path = asksaveasfile(initialfile='Untitled.txt', defaultextension='txt',filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*txt")])
        if in_path == " ":
            in_path = None
        else:
                #try to save file
            with open(in_path, "w") as infile:
                infile.write(txt.get(1.0, END))
                #change the window title
            root.title(os.path.basename(in_path))
    except:
            pass
```

Comment: I recommend this highly useful article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what values you have in variables. It is called "print debuging". OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it in console/terminal?  `asksaveasfile` doesn't gives filename but handler to opened file. To get filename you need `asksaveasfilename` instead of `asksaveasfile`. Use `print(in_path)` to see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

def saveFile():
    global in_path
    global txt

```
if in_path == '':
#save as new file
    in_path = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt', defaultextension='.txt',filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*.txt")])
    if in_path == "":
        in_path = None
    else:
        try:
            #try to save file
            with open(in_path, "w") as infile:
               infile.write(txt.get(1.0, END))


                #change the window title
            root.title(os.path.basename(in_path))
        except:
            pass
else:
        #try to save file
    with open(in_path, "w") as infile:
        infile.write(txt.get(1.0, END))
            #change the window title
            #infile.close()
        root.title(os.path.basename(in_path))
```

def saveAs():
    global in_path
    global txt
    try:
    #save as new file
        in_path = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt', defaultextension='.txt',filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"),("Text Documents","*.txt")])
        if in_path == " ":
            in_path = None
        else:
                #try to save file
            with open(in_path, "w") as infile:
                infile.write(txt.get(1.0, END))
                #change the window title
            root.title(os.path.basename(in_path))
    except:
            pass